# HTML Anchor tag issue

Tags: javascript, html

I have a piece of code like  below

```
<div>
<ul>
<li><a href="">Test1</a></li>
-------
-------
-------
<li><a href="">Test46</a></li>
</div>
```

It displays the html page with 46 links. The issue is when i scroll down and select the 46th or the ones just above this the page is going back to the top again. why is it happening so and is there any way to prevent it ?

Comment: Because the `href` has no value! `href=""`

Comment: You need to put a valid href target, to stop the scroll issue you are seeing, that is usually the default behavior since an empty href means you are referencing the same document.

Comment: What are you trying to do with these links?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`href` is blank thats why its going at top. You can use this instead of keeping blank:

```
<a href="javascript:void(0)">Test46</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

`href=""` contains the URL `""` which is a relative URL that resolves to "the URL of the current page".

When you click on the link, the browser follows it and goes to the current page.

As is normal (absent of any specific directive otherwise), when it goes to a page, it starts at the top.

---

If you don't want to link to the page: Why are you using a link in the first place?

If you just want something to dangle JavaScript from, use a button instead.

```
<button type="button">Test46</button>
```

You can style it to remove the default background colour and border, and set the colour scheme to match that of a link if you want it to look like a link.

Answer (score 0):

An empty string in the `href` attribute `<a href="">` means in modern browsers to go to the current page. This will basically just reload the current page, and as such it will go to the top.

One way to prevent from going to the top is to use `href="javascript:void(0)"`, as mentioned by **@Manwal** or you can simply remove the `href` attribute completely (*note in that case it will not show up as a clickable hyper-link*).

Comment: # will also link to the top of the page.

Comment: @Quentin I meant it stops the actual page reload, but I can see why that wouldn't help the user, so I removed it.